# What if the lowest granularity level can legitimately be null?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dimensional-modeling

I have a normalized database that I'm going to be using as a source for a dimensional data store; one of the *facts* I'm collecting is `Orders`, the normalized schema looks roughly like this:

[image: OrderDetailUnits -> OrderDetails -> OrderHeaders]

However when a new order is created in the source system, it doesn't have sizing information and so, there is no record for it in the `OrderDetailUnits` table.

I'm planning to make an `Orders` source table that flattens these tables into a single, denormalized table, but then I won't have a lowest-level record for quite a lot of the latest order data... which is *expected* as far as business is concerned.

How should I structure my `Orders` facts? Making separate "AllOrders" and "SizedOrders" fact tables / cubes would be annoying for the business users.

Answer (score 3):

I agree.  Your business users would not like "AllOrders" and "SizedOrders" fact tables.

I suggest creating a synthetic row in `OrderDetailUnits` for each `OrderDetail` where you have entries which are legitimately null.  I recommend populating `*NotApplicable*` or something like that for each dimension which is in the `OrderDetailUnits`.

While not exactly parallel with what you're doing, I suggest reading up on [Late Arrriving Dimensions](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/late-arriving-dimension/) to get some ideas.